# How to preview windows of a specific application in Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher, windows-7, dockbarx

I would like in Unity, to see a preview of the open windows of a specific application.
Just like Linux DockbarX (or windows 7).

Motivation example:
When I have several windows open of the same browser, I would like to navigate to the correct one.
Alt+Tab gives all the windows and not just the browser - is too much noise.

DockbarX gives the option to hover over the applications in the its launcher and it pops a preview of all open windows of that specific application.

How do I do this in Unity?

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible at the moment. Maybe in 11.10 (but do not hold your breath).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get is to use the Unity launcher.  If you are on a workspace that has your browser running, clicking on the browser icon in the Unity launcher will display all the open application windows for that browser.

If you are not on the workspace with your browser windows, clicking on the browser icon in the Unity launcher will take you to the workspace with the browser window you last interacted with.

A side note.  If you have all your browser windows on one workspace, you can cycle through your browser windows by clickig the middle mouse button on the top panel in the gap between the global menu and the indicators.

A nice guide to mouse and keyboard actions is at OMG Ubuntu
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/become-a-natty-power-user-in-no-time-using-this-unit-keyboard-shortcuts-wallpaper/