# Ubuntu 11.04 launcher... with tabs?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher, tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to preview windows of a specific application in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44400/how-to-preview-windows-of-a-specific-application-in-unity)

In Windows 7, if you have more of the same window open at the same time and you click on the icon, it pops out a preview-list of all the windows.

Is there anyway to achieve the same thing in Ubuntu 11.04? See below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll find that behavior available with Unity as well. Launcher icons will have multiple small arrows to the left of them when multiple windows of the same application are open. Click that application's icon again to change between individual windows.

You can edit the behavior of this and many, many other Unity/Compiz desktop settings using `CompizConfig Settings Manager` (ccsm), which you can find in the `Ubuntu Software Centre`.

Comment: It's similar to Dock Exposé in Mac OS X Snow Leopard. Click on the icon ... boom ... select the windows you want ... very very simple :D

Comment: Ok. Where can I find the setting to manipulate that behaviour, there's too many to sit here and sift through.

Comment: I found an image sampling what I am looking for. (Doesn't have to be exact)